# Laravel: Send HTTP request to own API with headers

Tags: laravel, httprequest

I want to consume my own API (with authentification) for my website which is on the same domain. For instance, if the user of the website wants to see the list of the posts:

**1.** He goes to `mywebsite/posts`, thus making a `GET /mywebsite/posts` request.

**2.** The web app dispatches the request and calls the `listPosts()` function of the `WebsiteController`.

**3.** The `listPosts()` function creates a new request to the API like that:

```
$token = 'd0aE73j...';
$request = Request::create('/api/posts', 'GET', [], [], [], [
    'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$token,   //The header for authentification
    'Accept' => 'application/json',        //The header supposed to prevent the error below
], []);
$response = Route::dispatch($request);
```

**4.** The JSON result of the request is passed and displayed in the view of the list of posts:

```
return view('mywebsite.listposts')->with('listPosts',$response);
```

The problem I have is at **3.**, the request returns an error:

> InvalidArgumentException: Route [login] not defined. in file C:[...]\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator.php on line 370

What I want to know is:

1) How to make a proper HTTP request with headers to my own API,

2) How to return a JSON instead of this error when the `Accept: application/json` is not present.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You might want to use [guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle) instead

Comment: Does this work when I want to consume my **own** API? Is it updated regularly?

Comment: Calling serwers api inside it is not good. The question: why you not call GET /api/posts directly from your client(browser) using ajax ? 
Alternative: To avoid call api inside api, you can call its Controller directly from previous controller

Comment: Yes and yes. Question back: why do you think it matter that is is your **own** API? You should handle your own API with the same care as you would with an external api.

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski For some data I agree with you, but not for all situations is javascript calling API's the best choice. Sometimes you want to handle things server side fist on the client of the API. Or at least sometimes you want to keep credentials secret and do not pass them to the browser for js.

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski Well, if I used AJAX I would need to write a `onload` Javascript function for the view, and I would need to painstakingly change the DOM for the list of posts; whereas I can only pass the results of the query to the view during templating.

Comment: @ThomasMoors AJAX doesn't allow cross-site requests, so I assumed that there were differences between external requjests and internal requests.

Comment: @JacopoStanchi Yes I agree, that's why I said I disagree with Kamil partially. (As constructive feedback, we should thank him still to take the time to write a comment).

Comment: Fair enough, thank you both.